# How to find empty and non empty cell element in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[image: Sheet Image]

As per the attached snapshot of spreadsheet, I have putted some values in the cell A2:A9 and Cell B2:B9. In the said array B2:B9 some cell elements are empty and some are non empty. I have build formula in the cell C2

```
=QUERY(A2:B,"select Col1 where Col2 is not null")
```

to find non empty cell. To find empty cell I have build a formula in cell D2

```
=QUERY(A2:B,"select Col1 where Col2 is  null")
```

But, unfortunately i am not able to find required result as given in the cell E2:E9 and F2:F9 as attached in the snapshot. So kindly help me to finding corresponding empty and non empty cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*`non-blank`*

```js
=arrayformula(if(B2:B<>"",A2:A,))
```

*`blank`*

```js
=arrayformula(if(B2:B="",A2:A,))
```

Answer (score 2):

There is function:

> ISBLANK()

which checks if cell is empty. So answer from @rockinfreakshow could be written as:

empty

> =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(B2:B),A2:A,))

Not empty:

> =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(NOT(ISBLANK(B2:B)),A2:A,))